# Calculate the expectation of Stratonovich integral

Tags: stochastic-integrals

how to Calculate the expectation of Stratonovich integral as follows?
$
\mathbb{E}\left[ \left( \int_0^t{s\mathrm{d}B_{s}^{2}} \right) \right] \text{、}\mathbb{E} \left[ \left( \int_0^t{s\mathrm{d}B_{s}^{2}} \right) ^2 \right] \text{、}\mathbb{E}\left[ \exp \left( \int_0^t{s\mathrm{d}B_s} \right) \right] 
$

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.